# Jenkinspipline Git SCM checkout with multiple branches

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, git-branch

I see in the Jenkins Pipeline SCM Step documentation that multiple branches can be passed into the checkout step: 
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#checkout-general-scm

e.g.

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: 'release-1.2'], [name: 'master']], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions: [], 
    submoduleCfg: [], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[]]
])
```

What does that actually mean passing multiple branches in git terms since only one branch can be checked out at a time? Above documentation does not elaborate on that detail.

Comment: According to `If left blank, all branches will be examined for changes and built.` in the doc, it seems that if any branches are specified, these branches will be examined for changes and built.

Comment: @ElpieKay I'm wondering what "examined" means in git terms and which branch will be visible for the build etc?

Comment: To check if the specified branches have new commits. If one is updated, the branch is checked out and built. I'm not sure how it works. But, one branch can be checked out at a time in one working tree. A git repository can have multiple working trees at the same time (by `git workree add`). The multiple branches may be checked out into different working trees, or one by one in the main working tree. It's also possible to clone multiple repositories, each for one branch to be checked out.

Comment: I saw that for e.g. `branches: [[name: 'release-1.2'], [name: 'master']]` I ended up with master checked out in the working directory. Is this the expected behaviour and the branches stated before are pulled and checked out before?